# Help with counter-example on uniformly convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Show that the sequence:
$$h_n(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{x}{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) \mbox{ if } x=0\mbox{ or }x\notin\mathbb{Q}\\
x(b+\frac{1}{n})(1+\frac{1}{n})\mbox{ if } x\in\mathbb{Q}.
\end{cases}$$

Does not uniformly converges at any bounded interval.

Answer (score 0):

This is false. On any bounded interval, $h_n$ converges uniformly to $bx\cdot\chi_{\mathbb Q}(x).$

Comment: You're on your own.